# Efficient way of reading data from another contract?

Tags: solidity, gas

I'm trying to get a bunch of data from one contract to another, and I can't figure out a cheap (gas) way of doing it.

Contract A looks like below:

```
contract A {
    struct Info {
        string uri;
        uint8 itype;
        int32 attr1;
        int32 attr2;
        int32 attr3;
        int32 attr4;
        int32 attr5;
        int32 attr6;
    }

  function getInfoWithData() public view override returns (uint256[] memory, address[] memory, Info[] memory) {
     // returns (uint256[] ids, addresses[] addresses, Info[] infos)
  }
```

I'm calling this from contract B like:

```
contract B {
    function update() public override {
        (uint256[] memory _ids, address[] memory _addresses, A.Info[] memory _infos) = A.getInfoWithData();

        // Do stuff here.
    }
}
```

If it tries to return 200 entries the gas costs are already something like $2600, and I expect 10,000 infos.

How could this be optimized? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Reading more than 10,000 bytes from storage is never cheap.

Also there is a security concern with your code: You should almost never have an array that large, since such an operation is likely to extend the block gas limit currently in effect ([DoS with block gas limit](https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-128#dos-addresssol)).

A safer strategy is to use a mapping to store this information, and possibly store data off-chain (e.g., ipfs) and secure it by storing a hash in your contract.